# Conditional help ifelse statement

Tags: r, piecewise

We have the following piecewise equality for a dataset:

```
tenure_new == tenure iftenure <= exper 
tenure_new == exper iftenure> exper
```

So the code i wrote is:

```
tenure_new <- ifelse(wage2$tenure <= wage2$exper,wage2$tenure, wage2$exper)
```

We want to get the mean value, but the answer we got is not being accepted - not sure what else to do.

I don't want the answer, just some directions on what i might be overlooking.

Here is the problem question:

[image: PROBLEM QUESTION]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) for what this would mean in R. Note that an image of code, data, or problem statement is not very useful for others.

Comment: The definition of `tenure_new` looks fine.  If the properly rounded value of its mean isn't being accepted by some automatic grading system, the problem might lie with the grading system. Your question lacks adequate context. It isn't really answerable based on the limited information that you have provided.

Comment: If `round(mean(tenure_new), 2)` is giving you 6.51 then the problem is not you.

Comment: Please show the code you used to get the mean value and state what that value is.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways that you can do it. But to keep things simple I'll show the traditional `for` loop approach with base R, the `mapply` approach with base R, and share the `tidyverse` approach also.

## Base R Approach - Using `for` loops

```r
library(wooldridge)

data(wage2)

# Traditional solution
# Make new variable
wage2$tenure_new<- NA

for(i in 1:length(wage2$tenure)){
  if(wage2$tenure[i]<= wage2$exper[i]){
    wage2$tenure_new[i]<- wage2$tenure[i]
  }else{
    wage2$tenure_new[i]<- wage2$exper[i]
  }
}

# mean of tenure_new
round(mean(wage2$tenure_new),2)
# Output> [1] 6.51
```

## Base R Approach- using `mapply`

A really small amount of code, but hard to read if you don't know R well.

```r
round(mean(mapply(function(x,y) if(x<=y){x}else{y},x=wage2$tenure,y=wage2$exper)),2)
```

## `tidyverse` Approach

(Actually you can use `dplyr` package alone but I personally like to load `tidyverse` in its entirety.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

wage2 %>% 
  transmute(tenure_new=ifelse(tenure<=exper,tenure,exper)) %>% 
  colMeans() %>% 
  round(2)

# Output> tenure_new 
#               6.51
```

Comment: Downvoting because your 2 base R approaches are terribly unidiomatic. They are less efficient versions of the code OP has in the question. There is nothing "traditional" in R about using a for loop instead of vectorized functions.

Comment: @GregorThomas you're entitled to your opinion, but the base R examples are my attempts to educate and provide intuition.

Comment: I would expect some commentary then, as I'm not clear on what concepts you're trying to illustrate or what intuition those examples provide...  The for loop could be "if you're using a different language that's not vectorized, you might approach the problem this way...". The `mapply` seems like a way to obfuscate the simple `ifelse(wage2$tenure <= wage2$exper,wage2$tenure, wage2$exper)` OP posts in the question?

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean, but your base R examples seem less readable and less efficient than what OP has in the question. So I really am confused about why you're including them.

Comment: `round(mean(mapply(function(x,y) if(x<=y {x}else{y},x=wage2$tenure,y=wage2$exper)),2)`, which you identify as "really small amount of code but hard to read" isn't as short as OP's very readable  `ifelse(wage2$tenure <= wage2$exper,wage2$tenure, wage2$exper)` (which could, of course, be wrapped in `mean()` just as easily. And `mapply` will almost certainly have more overhead than `ifelse` in this case, making it less efficient too.